# Error when using operator << with implicitly converted non-fundamental data types

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction

I have a struct that works as a wrapper for other types as follows:

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
  A& operator=(const T& value){
    m_value = value;
    return *this;
  }

  operator T() const {
    return m_value;
  }

private:
  T m_value;
};
```

I use it like this:

```
int main() {
  A<int> a;
  a = 5;                  // Copy assignment constructor
  std::cout << a << "\n"; // Implicit conversion to int
}
```

which works as expected. My problem occurs when using non-fundamental types as the following example shows:

```
int main() {
  A<std::complex<int>> c;
  c = std::complex<int>(2, 2);  
  std::cout << c << "\n";
}
```

The snippet above raises an `invalid operands to binary expression` error.

Why does this error occur? Why isn't the overloaded operator `<<` of `std::complex<int>` used with the implicitly converted `A<std::complex<int>>`?

Comment: It works for non template template arguments of `A`, it doesn't for template template arguments. See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ad05b4b564bab1b

Comment: @YSC Great observation! Feel free to edit the title of this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stream operators for `std::complex` are template functions.  They will not be invoked unless you actual have a `std::complex` as no conversions happens in template argument deduction.  This means the compiler will not find a suitable overload to print a `A<std::complex<int>>`

You're first case for works because [`std::basic_ostream::operator <<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) is overloaded to take an `int` and you are allowed one user defined conversion is overload resolution.

---

As a work arround you can define your own `operator <<` that takes your wrapper and forward to the underlying types' `operator <<`.  That would look like

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const A<T>& a)
{
    return os << static_cast<T>(a);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there any work around to achieve the behavior I planed to get?

Comment: @datell, the simplest work around is define `template <typename T> operator<<(std::ostream&, A<T> const&);`.

Comment: @datell I've added one to the answer.